# Cache._cache.flush_all () not working, How can I clear the cache with django and memcached?

Tags: python, django, memcached

Cache._cache.flush_all () not working
How can I clear the cache with django and memcached?

Comment: Did you tried `from django.core.cache import cache; cache.clear()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Django documentation for [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/cache/#basic-usage)

> Finally, if you want to delete all the keys in the cache, use
>   cache.clear(). Be careful with this; clear() will remove everything
>   from the cache, not just the keys set by your application.

You can also flush content of memcached by connecting by telnet or nc and executing flush_all

```
echo 'flush_all' | nc localhost 11211
```

Comment: I do not get error, but it does not clear my cache
I have the whole website with cache

Comment: @user3328955 https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/Commands#flushall